# Sql insert command in C#

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I'm currently creating a small C# program that inserts data from files into a postgres table.

The code that does the insertion looks like this:

```
 NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO :table(text) VALUES (:word);", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("table", table);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("word", line);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But every time it tries to execute the "ExecuteNonquery" line I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' occurred in Npgsql.dll
Additional information: ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "("
```

I can connect to the database I have checked. The variables table and line also have the correct values at runtime. I just can't figure out what the problem is..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't know C# specifically, but generally in most languages you cannot parameterize the table name, only the values in the where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the table can't be a parameter.

What you can do however is use string concatting/formatting for that:

```
string table = "table";
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Format(@"INSERT INTO {0}(text) VALUES (:word);", table), con);
```

Guess that would work (didn't test it).

Comment: I think you would need to cancel out the table strings special characters before you do string.Format .. (Would be pretty bad to get ; DELETE FROM tablenamehere; --)

Comment: Of course, but why would you accept user input for the table name? Doesn't make sense. But it can be useful for maintainability, define the table name once, use it everywhere.

Comment: However, this is a huge SQL injection security hole.  You should either find a way to eliminate the need to dynamically specify the table name, or at a minimum do string escaping of any string you use for `table`.  A java method would be `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql()`.  Look for something similar in C# and don't try to do it by hand yourself -- it's a lot of work.

Comment: @Leon Cullens Well I have a lot of files that are generated in a specific way that go into different tables and I need to insert them from a shell script(requirement by the client)..

Comment: @MikeRyan, it's only vulnerable if you accept user input. Not if you just define the name of the table in your code and use that.

Comment: Still, you never know what information would someday go there.. :)

Comment: If you know the names of the tables beforehand you could use whitelisting and check if the supplied table name is in your collection of table names.